# Angular2 auxiliary route not working

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to use an **auxiliary** route in my angular 2 application but somehow the auxiliary route is not found.
The **home.page.component.ts** is loaded within my primary outlet, which is working properly.
*I modified the code below to simplify it for readability*

> **home.page.component.ts**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/','childRouter:wepays']">WePays</a></li>
</ul>

<router-outlet name="childRouter"></router-outlet>
```

> **routes.ts**

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig, RouterOutlet }  from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from '../components/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from '../components/home.component';
import { WePaysComponent } from '../components/wepays.component';

const routes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/login',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
    },
    {

        path: 'wepays',
        component: WePaysComponent,
        outlet: 'childRouter'   
    }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

> **When clicking on:** [routerLink]="['/','childRouter:wepays']"

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find the outlet childRouter to load 'WePaysComponent'
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10351

Comment: Doesn't look like it. I guess they'll strive to get this fixed for the next Angular2 update (RC.5).